# QListWidget How to raise an event once I reach end of QListWidget

Tags: qt

In QListWidget, there are many items. I want to raise an event once I reach end of the list. How can I do?

Comment: What do you mean you reach end of the list? Do you mean you click on the last index of QListWidget?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
          Widget(QWidget* parent = 0);
    private:
          QListWidget *listWidget;
          QScrollBar *verticalScrollBar;
    private slots:
          void onScrollBarValueChanged(int);
    signals:
          void signalToEmit();
}

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    listWidget = new QListWidget(this);   
    verticalScrollBar = listWidget.verticalScrollBar();
    connect(verticalScrollBar,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
    this,SLOT(onScrollBarValueChanged(int)));
}

void Widget::onScrollBarValueChanged(int value)
{
    if(value == verticalScrollBar->maximum())
        emit signalToEmit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my question above isn't clearly. What I need is I move the scrollbar (or the cursor) in QListWidget (not touch any item). when the scrollbar reach the end, it will raise an event.

Answer (score 1):

Three year later, but I was looking for an answer for that and I came up with an easy way :D

Maybe It's not that "clean" but here you go:

```
QListWidget* mylist;

QScrollBar* scrollBar = mylist->findChildren<QScrollBar*>().at(1);
    /* position 0 -> horizontal */
    /* position 1 -> vertical   */
connect(scrollBar, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(ScrollBarChanged(int)));
```

Now you create the slot:

```
void TabWebView::ScrollBarChanged(int value)
{
    QScrollBar *sender = (QScrollBar*)QObject::sender();

    if (sender->maximum() == value)
        /* Do Things */
}
```